# Java 8 Optional multi-level null check

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type

I am working on a program that consumes methods which return `Optional` and I need to iterate over that and create a new object. How do I do that?

```
import java.util.Optional;

class Info {
    String name;
    String profileId;

    Info(String name, String profileId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }
}

class Profile {
    String profileId;
    String profileName;

    Profile(String profileId, String profileName) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }
}

class Content {
    String infoName;
    String profileName;

    Content(String infoName, String profileName) {
        this.infoName = infoName;
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }

    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "Content{" + "infoName='" + infoName + '\'' + ", profileName='" + profileName + '\'' + '}';
    }
}

class InfoService {
    Optional<Info> findByName(String name){ //todo implementation }
}

class ProfileService {
   Optional<Profile> findById(String id) { //todo implementation }
}

class ContentService {

    Content createContent(Info i, Profile p) {
        return new Content(i.name, p.profileName);
    }

    Content createContent(Info i) {
        return new Content(i.name, null);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    InfoService infoService = new InfoService();
    ProfileService profileService = new ProfileService();
    ContentService contentService = new ContentService();

    //setup
    Info i = new Info("info1", "p1");
    Profile p = new Profile("p1", "profile1");

    // TODO: the following part needs to be corrected
    Optional<Info> info = infoService.findByName("info1");

    if (!info.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    } else {
         Optional<Profile> profile = profileService.findById(info.get().profileId);

         Content content;

         if (!profile.isPresent()) {
             content = contentService.createContent(info);
         } else {
             content = contentService.createContent(info, profile);
         }

        System.out.println(content);
     }
}
```

My understanding of the Java Optional is to reduce the `if null` checks but I still can't do it without the `if` checks. Is there a better solution to use `map` or `flatMap` and have a concise code?

Comment: there is an `if else` contradiction in return types.

Comment: The simplicity of the question doesn't match the complexity of your example. Please rephrase (if it's indeed a complex problem) or simplify the example to an MCVE

Comment: @nullpointer can you explain what you mean? This code is a re-write of what I am doing (I don't want to use the same Models used in the company codebase)

Comment: `if (!info.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }` I meant this part specifically within a void method,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the about the best you can get. `map` will only execute the lambda if it's present. `orElseGet` will only execute the lambda if it's not.

```
return infoService.findByName("info1")
    .map(info ->
        profileService.findById(info.profileId)
            .map(profile -> contentService.createContent(info, profile))
            .orElseGet(() -> contentService.createContent(info))
    );
```

Comment: Nice one, Michael. Is there a way to chain `infoService.findByName()` at the beginning using `map` or `flatMap` to make the code even more concise?

Comment: @bak Yeah, just needs another `map` call. Edited my answer